# Using a byte password with microsoft.data.sqlite

Tags: c#, sqlite, .net-core, passwords, sqlcipher

I have a test console project (.Net Core 3.1) using the Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.Core (3.1.0) and SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_e_sqlcipher (2.0.2) packages. When I run the following code I get a "Syntax Error" exception thrown when the "Pragma Key = " command is executed.

My understanding is that the SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_e_sqlcipher package is a build of SQLCipher so supports byte array passwords (and the documentation for SQLCipher says this format is supported). Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

```
            if (File.Exists(@"c:\temp\enctest.db")) File.Delete(@"c:\temp\enctest.db");

            string connectionString = new SqliteConnectionStringBuilder(@"Data Source=c:\temp\enctest.db").ToString();

            using SqliteConnection conn = new SqliteConnection(connectionString);
            conn.Open();

            using SqliteCommand comm = conn.CreateCommand();
            comm.CommandText = "PRAGMA key = x'2DD29CA851E7B56E4697B0E1F08507293D761A05CE4D1B628663F411A8086D99'";
            comm.ExecuteNonQuery();

            comm.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE Test(TestId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, TestField TEXT NOT NULL COLLATE NOCASE);";
            comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: according to this page: https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/sqlcipher-api/#key you need double quotes around `"x'2DD...'"`

Comment: Not sure how to flag this as an answer but thanks :) that worked.